what is the area of the square?
What is the area of the square?
I think that the height of A is phi+1, but i dont know how demostrate it.
I know that the problem is probably very easy. Sorry and thanks for helping me


@Dominique I suspect $ABCD$ is a square symmetric about the $y$-axis with $A$ and $B$ on the parabola $y=x^2$ and $D$ in the line $y=-3x+1$.

Denote $A=(-a,b)$, $B=(a,b)$, $C=(a,d)$ and $D=(-a,d)$. Then we have the following relations: $$b = a^2 \text{ and } d = 3a+1. $$
Hence $|AB| = 2a$ and $|DA| = 3a+1-a^2$ and they need to be equal since it is a suqare by hypothesis. We get $a^2-a-1=0$ which gives us $a = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ since it is positive by assumption.
The side of the square is therefore $1+\sqrt{5}$ and the area is $(1+\sqrt{5})^2$.

You want to know the coordinates of $A=(x,y)$, which are two variables:
There are two relations here which should give you two equations:
$(x,y)$ is on the quadratic curve.
$(x,y-2x)$ is on the line.

Yes A is in quadratic curve and B too. Is this a comment, right? Edit my question, please.
